# Yii2 mpdf 6.0 custom font ignored

Tags: php, fonts, yii2, config, mpdf

**Configuration:**

- yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced v2.0.6
- mpdf/mpdf - v6.0.0 - installed through composer

**Goal**

Use custom font without configuring it in vendor (vendor/mpdf/mpdf/config_fonts.php).

**Approaches**

I followed instrructions on the official site: https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-6-x.html

1. adding fonts to defined _MPDF_TTFONTPATH
2. edit fontdata in my mpdf instance (because I do not want to edit it in config_fonts.php)
3. set font in html
4. does not apply to my case (To use the font with specific languages)

Following is the way it should work regarding the documentation:

```
define('_MPDF_TTFONTPATH', '/web/assets/fonts/');
define('_MPDF_TEMP_PATH', '/web/images/mpdf/tmp/');
define('_MPDF_TTFONTDATAPATH', '/web/assets/fonts/ttfontdata/');

$mpdf = new \mPDF();

$mpdf->fontdata["vidaloka"] = [
    'R' => "Vidaloka-Regular.ttf",
];

$mpdf->mpdf('', 'A4', '', 'vidaloka', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'P');
```

Unfortunately it does not work. My pdf is created, but the font is ignored.
It only works, when I define the font directly in vendor/mpdf/mpdf/config_fonts.php

So I invested a lot of time and tried a lot of different approaches. f.e. like adding:

```
$mpdf->fontdata = ["vidaloka" => [
    'R' => "Vidaloka-Regular.ttf",
    ]
];

$mpdf->default_available_fonts[] = 'vidaloka';

$mpdf->AddFont('vidaloka', 'R');
```

None of these made a difference. When dumping fontdata, vidaloka appears in the array every time, but when building the pdf it is simply ignored.

**How can I make mpdf apply the font without editing the mpdf config_font.php?**

Thank you in advance for your time.

*FYI: Upgrading to a higher version is unfortunately not an option*

Comment: `define('_MPDF_TTFONTPATH', '/web/assets/fonts/');`
You should verify if your fonts are really in the root folder /web. My guess is, that you need to remove the / and leave it out or replace it with something like `getcwd()`.

Comment: I have already verified that. The path is correct, the fonts are really in the folder. And they can be accessed.